# Groups taking so long.... finally time out?

Tags: 2007, groups

I have around 300,000 users in the site collection and around 250 groups in the same site collection. When I am trying to open any group to get users in it. It is taking so long and finally it is showing `Request TimeOut`. Other than that.... Site Collection is working fine.

How can open groups normally without delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is time to reduce the number of users in your SharePoint groups. Have you looked at using AD security groups instead of naming each user individually?